# excel vba delete sheets run-time error subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

i try to delete all the sheets which start from Sheet5 to last sheet but i got "run-time error subscript out of range".

```
Dim x as Long
For x = 5 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(x).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next
```

The result it did delete but only Sheet5, Sheet7 and Sheet9 but Sheet6 and Sheet8 still there. Grey debug button and i wondering where's the error.
Please help because keep struggle on this and can't get through. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that it's an issue in your logic of deleting the sheets. 
At the beginning of the loop `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(x).Delete` will delete Sheet5.

However, once Sheet5 is deleted Sheet6 will take its place, so ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5) will equal Sheet6.

Your counter is x = 6 at this point though, so it will delete Sheet7, which is at position ThisWorkbook.Sheets(6).

Sheet 8 will take its place and your counter will be x=7 at this point. This will delete Sheet9 which is at position ThisWorkbook.Sheets(7).

The counter will be x=8 now and the code will try to delete ThisWorkbook.Sheets(8), however, this worksheet doesn't exist --> Subscript out of Range

Comment: To be added, VBA will delete whichever `Sheet` is at that position, so if the `Sheets` would be shuffled or named it will delete whichever `Sheet` is in position `5` as a start.

Comment: many thanks to @daZza i didn't realized after deleted Sheet5, Sheet6 will become Sheet5, so i just need to keep delete Sheet5 using loop method.

Comment: True, I thought to complicated there :P

Comment: Thank you @DragonSamu, Yes, i already keep those sheets i need always stick on top 4 position. :)